# Is there such a thing as a single-sided tri-fold leaflet?

Tags: print-design, print-production, digital-printing, document-setup, folding

Do single-sided tri-fold leaflets exist or are they basically unheard of?

Failing that, are there any other folded documents that are only printed on one side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the purpose of the item, *any* kind of paper item can be printed on a single side.

*Flyer type* trifolds are typically printed on both sides, like commercial designs, restaurant menus, product showcase, etc.

However some *mostly* text, *mostly* black & white, eg. bank statements, invoices & bills, legal letters, etc kind of trifolds, those can be single sided, A4 triple folds, made to fit inside DL envelopes (or the equivalent US formats).

Greeting cards *in some cases* can be seen as a folded item, with a blank (or near-blank) inside.

Answer (score 2):

Besides invoices and such, I can think about maps only printed on one side.

But one thing that needs to be considered is that folding is as expensive or more expensive than printing at least 1 color, so in order to optimize the printed medium it is a good idea not to waste one side of the paper.

The specific case of a map could be that it is going to fit on a wall, and the folding is only for delivery (the same as fitting an invoice in an envelope), but the folding ruins the product. But even in this case, someone could sell the back side as a space for advertising.

---

**Sequence**

One important thing is that folding also has the purpose of sequence, so, in that regard, a trifold leaflet has a sequence of faces. It has a cover and a subsequent series of faces.

Depending on the type of folding, there are different expectations of content.

In case 1, after seeing cover A, printed on this A-side (blue) we reveal face B that is on the B side of the paper. The absence of content is evident.

But in case 2, we can extend all the paper and see printed side A. In order to see face B we need to turn the paper. There is no missing or expected content. Content B is a separate element.

[image]

This folding could even be used in other things besides paper. It could be a screen on an expo stand or something.

> Failing that, are there any other folded documents that are only printed on one side?

I can think of folders, covers for books, and other protective materials.